# How can I use table names containing slashes in SQL performance trace transaction st05 ("Explain SQL")?

Tags: performance, opensql, sap-basis

How can I select table names that do contain slashes in the inline SQL performance analysis (aka "Explain SQL") of transaction `ST05`?

I tried escaping them with `'/table/name'` or `"/table/name"` or `"\/table\/name"`. None of them worked.

Works for tables without slashes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

but not for tables with slashes (e.g. from a namespace):

```sql
SELECT * FROM /table/name.
```

Comment: Have you tried without escaping? It works for me.

Comment: @konstantin : in the "Explain SQL" screen, you must use the SQL syntax corresponding to your database, not [ABAP SQL](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopensql.htm) (ABAP SQL is a SQL-like language which is the greatest common divisor of the SQL of all databases supported by ABAP-based systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Double Quotes to get the plan. Using quotes it is important to write the table names in capital letters.

```
SELECT * FROM "/TABLE/NAME"
```

The actual error occurs in the report `RSXPLORA` in form `db_explain_plan` where the undebuggable function `DB_EXPLAIN_PLAN` is called. It varies depending on `sy-dbsys(3)` which is `ORA` in my case.